# How to call Realtime update api in google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

URL: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/update

I want to copy Realtime File A  to  REaltime File B. Now  I  have  call https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get   successfully got the JSON data from  File A.

But  I  fail to  call update to  update data to file B, return error:

> {"error":{"code":500,message":null}}

Any one can help me? Here is my code:

```
make_request=function(params, callback) { 
   params['callback'] = function(data){ 
      if (callback != null) { callback(data); }  
   return gapi.client.request(params); 
} 

content=localStorage["realtimeA data"]; 
boundary = "-------314159265358979323846";
delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n"; close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--"; base64Data = btoa(content); 
multipartRequestBody = delimiter + "Content-Type: " + "application/json" + "\r\n" + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + "\r\n" + base64Data + close_delim;

params = { 
   path: "/upload/drive/v2/files/0B4ihvYUW4AU1WEQyRTEwaGRNaXM/realtime",
   method: "PUT",        
   params: { uploadType: "media", fileId: "0B4ihvYUW4AU1WEQyRTEwaGRNaXM" }, 
   headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"" }, 
   body: multipartRequestBody 
}; 



make_request(params,function callback(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data));} );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do a multipart upload.  The supported [options](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/update) are simple or resumable.  You probably want to do a [simple upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#simple) (which is actually what you are specifying in the request.